# Order details page as pdf

Tags: magento2.3, orders, pdf

I need to make an extension to generate order details page as a pdf file when I click in print pdf button.
help please

Answer (score 0):

You can start to check how magento is building pdf order invoices in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice`

All you should need to do is to create a custom class that will extends `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` and where you will write anything you want in the pdf.

That's for the pdf creation part...to retrieve the order details, just go threw usual by repository and so on.

If this doesn't answer your question, please be more specific about where you are stuck.